# How strong is parallels plesk 11 inbuilt firewall for linux os? from an newbie

Tags: firewall, hardening

I am new to Linux Dedicated server hosting and **plesk panel 11** and i would like to know about inbuilt plesk 11 firewall **security** features and how harden it is?

Comment: DOS attacks no, firewalls aren't designed to stop DOS attacks - *DOS mitigation devices are*. Its a firewall, it closes ports - it doesn't add security.

Comment: goddamit, it's a sunday. There's no need to post two questions less than 30 minutes apart.

Comment: @tombull89 Serverfault dosen't have restrictions on posting posts on sunday

Comment: @Sampath, no it doesn't. It *does* have rules against double posting questions, probably caused by the fact it's a sunday and there's not as many people on, meaning you didn't get an answer and meaning you posted it twice.

Comment: @tombull89 yes you are right, i respect your thoughts,but one question refers how much plesk 11 firewall is harden , another question refers do plesk have inbuilt firewall for linux , both have different view angles for an newbie like me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is strong enough and is powered by iptables although it is not very flexible. But having some knowledge of iptables you can do pretty much whatever you want.

By the way there is a [board](https://security.stackexchange.com/) specialized in firewall and security.

Answer (score 1):

To be a bit pedantic, it's no stronger than your configuration and the underlying application and kernel.

Plesk is not, in and of itself, a firewall any more than it's an operating system. It's a web front-end for the base OS's tools and applications.

NetFilter/IPTables is an excellent network filtering tool. You should also spend some working with the command line and figure out how Linux works.